# C# Trying to avoid duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

```
var multiples = from i in Enumerable.Range(min, (max - min))
                        from r in roots
                        where i % r == 0
                        select i;
```

For example, if `roots = {2,10}` it would select `20` twice.

Is it possible to avoid duplicates here?

Comment: If you use `multiples.Distinct()` afterwards, that won't contain duplicates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Any()` instead of a full Cartesian join:

```
var multiples = from i in Enumerable.Range(min, (max - min))
                where roots.Any(r => i % r == 0)
                select i;
```

This has the added advantage that it will stop testing elements in `roots` as soon as it finds one that succeeds, and it does not require a second pass through to pull out the distinct elements.

Comment: Surely this is smarter than `.Distinct()` in this case.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Oh yeah. A good one. This is what happens when one takes time to really think about what is being done in the question.

Answer (score 10):

Use the [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx)

```
var multiples = (from i in Enumerable.Range(min, (max - min))
                 from r in roots
                 where i % r == 0
                 select i).Distinct();
```

This works well on simple types like `string` and `int`. <strike>not very well on anonymous types.</strike>

In your case the `i` is an `int`, and it should therefore be ably to sort out dublicates.

**EDIT**

It *does* infact works on anonymous types (see Jeppe's comment).  because as @Jeppe said the anonymous types have a "good" `Equals` enabeling the `Distict` to determin if the to objects are equal / dublicates.

Comment: @user1376243 please accept the answer by clicking the tick if it resolves your query.

Comment: You: _not very well on anonymous types_ It (`.Distinct()`) works great on anonymous types provided that the type of each property of the anonumous type is a type with "good" `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implementations. The anonymous type will have (automatically) `Equals` and `GetHashCode` which implement "coordinate-wise" equality comparison.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I didn't think the anonymous types where that smart. But it makes sence that they should be able to do a "good" equals. Thanks for the heads up. edit pending.

Answer (score 3):

Use [DISTINCT](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/741ecf5b-d24e-44e4-9ba7-603348d8c9bf/)

```
var multiples = (from i in Enumerable.Range(min, (max - min))
                        from r in roots
                        where i % r == 0
                        select i).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `Distinct()` Method

```
var multiples = (from i in Enumerable.Range(min, (max - min))
                 from r in roots
                 where i % r == 0
                 select i).Distinct();
```